# Column with default date with Slick 3.1.0

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have an `events` table with these columns

```
 _________________________
|___name_____|___time_____|
|            |            |
|____________|____________|
```

The value of time column is auto generated with the current date at creation time.

Equivalently, I have this case class to represent a row in the table.

```
case class Event(name: String, time: Option[java.sql.Date] = None)
```

Now, the problem is that when I try to insert an event with

```
val event = Event("blah blah blah")
events += event
```

Slick actually insert `('blah blah blah', null)` instead of just `('blah blah blah')`, and that makes the time field `null`.

If I set a constraint on the time column to `NOT NULL`, then I would get an error for the attempt to insert `null`.

Of course I can decompose my `event` object and perform the insert, but I wonder if there is a kind of mapping that tells Slick that this column is auto-generated, like in the case with the auto-increment id column:

```
def id = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc)
```

#### Update

So I try setting the time column as follow

```
def time = column[java.sql.Date]("time", O.AutoInc)
```

and it seems to work.

The document for `AutoInc` states that it is use for `auto increment` and `auto generated` column.

Though I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: It is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks mohit for the confirmation :)

Comment: What if you want the timestamp to be stored when you create AND when you update the row?

Comment: That is configured within PostgreSql. Slick only concerns about mapping Scala and RDB tables, and generate sql from Scala code. `O.AutoInc` is just a marker saying that Slick should let the database handle this column. You will want to look at creating function and trigger to update timestamp.

Comment: Looks like hack which breaks model. Autogenerated date means I never want to get null in the field. I want DB to set the field value. So *case class Event(name: String, time: Option[java.sql.Date] = None)* None will appear only once during first insert. I hit the same issue...